# Trying to connect ldap users two or more subdomains to nifi

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi, ldap-query

I have setup three node secure NIFI cluster and integrated with LDAP for user login .
my doubts

1. In login-identity-providers.xml can we add multiple USER Search Base of ldap.(i tried by adding multiple usersearchbase but failed)
2. In LDAP user search should happen on multiple sub domains eg : DC=example1,dc=example,dc=com 
   DC=example2,dc=example,dc=com 
   on User-search-base in login-identity-providers.xml
3. TO achieve mutitenancy in ldap what is the configuration changes we need to make in identity provider.xml
4. tenant1 user should access process group define for tenant 1 itself and its not access for tenant2 users

[image: login-identiyt-provider.xml]

Comment: Provide more information. Show the <provider> section. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, AND Assuming you are using Microsoft Active Directory if you use:


FOLLOW
It may work.

We also sometimes might use the Global Catalog (as then there are no referrals)

I also am guessing that the "empty" parameters should be removed (but I do NOT know how NIFI works).

I would suggest you also do tests with a LDAP Browser to make sure you know what your LDAP tree looks like. We use [Apache Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/), but there are others.

More data on if it is Microsoft Active Directory and  refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask